# Layout inflater - for only part of a layout in another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application, I have a layout  list_item.xml with 3 textviews which are filled from an array and I want to inflate this 3 textviews alone in another layout. The layout in which I want to inflate is a separate xml file layout_result.xml which has a single button and android search widget.

layout file for list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="#F0F8FF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ProductName"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ProductName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="New Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="New Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Status"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Status"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="New Text" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout for list_resut.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="#F0F8FF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="118dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >
    </SearchView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/searchView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Problem** I faced when I tried to include search widget and button within list_item.xml and inflating them was that the search widget and button were being inserted in each of the 3 textview element.

So I created this separate layout list_result.xml which holds only the search widget and the button.

**Question**, is there anyway where I can place this list_item.xml with the textview results within list_result.xml to over come this error?

My layout inflater for list_item looks like this,

```
 public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);

            TextView txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            TextView txtID= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ID);
            TextView txtStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Status);

            txtName.setText(list.get(i).getProductName());
            txtID.setText(list.get(i).getProductID());
            txtStatus.setText(list.get(i).getStatus());
            return itemView;
       }
    }
```

Comment: include is not inflating. btw I read three times and I dont get the problem. Could you rephrase a little bit?

Comment: Hello, blackbelt, I have rephrased my problem now. Hope it is clear!

Comment: I too have read several times and am thoroughly confused. However, what you may be trying to do is want your `list_resut.xml` as the layout in `setContentView()` for your `Activity` and add a `ListView` to it. Then you inflate your `TextView`s layout in `getView()` as you are doing now.

Comment: Hi codeMagic, yes I tried this earlier, but I always used to get an error saying "No view found for id". So, I asked if there is any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just create a single layout XML. Not sure how you did it previously but you could do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </RelativeLayout/>
    <SearchView/>
    <Button/>
 </RelativeView>
```

If you want to keep the XML separate and then combine them at runtime, you still need a "container" for the inflated text views. You could use a FrameLayout as the container. Something like this for example:

results.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout/>
    <SearchView/>
    <Button/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

items.xml

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
</RelativeView/>
```

And then you can insert the textviews into the other layout like this:

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayoutId);
container.addChild(yourInflaterItemsView);
```

Hope this helps